# Angular directive with "E", cannot addClass

Tags: javascript, angularjs, element, addclass, directive

learning angularjs recently, I have a question about directive. When I create an "E", then try to add a class call "panel"(which just set background color to red) on it, it does not work, but when I create an "A", it actually works. Anybody know why it happens?

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'world';
});

app.directive("pop", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div button>' +
      'popup window, hello' +
      '</div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      test(element);
    }
  }
});


app.directive("button", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
     // test(element);
    }
  }
})

function test(element) {
  element.bind("mouseenter", function() {
    element.addClass("panel");
  });
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/9cLRYIaHH4Rl4bO5GAOp?p=preview

Comment: I clicked on the plunker link, saw the 'E' directive declared in the HTML, moused over it, and the background color changed to red. Am I missing something?

Comment: try this, http://plnkr.co/edit/9cLRYIaHH4Rl4bO5GAOp?p=preview I actually find the problem, I try to print element.html(), found out that our customized element is the parent of template. So when I do "element.find("div").addClass("panel")", it actually works. That means when we add class on customized class, the class function is not working. I am think that might be the problem that when we use customized elements, all attrs belong to its only scope, in other words, class attribute in customized elements doesn't have the same functions as the one in normal element, say div.

Answer (score 0):

If you add `position:absolute;` to the css of .panel it works as expected see plunkr below. The issue here is the default styling for a custom tag element rather than anything to do with angular.

see http://plnkr.co/edit/CEyCzfNu1gWQAe0q8VbP?p=preview

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. It works but there is a problem. When you set absolute position, after move onto this element, it disappear. I found out that in angular, customized element is actually the parent element of template. So when you add class, it is actually added on customized element, rather than on template. try this : http://plnkr.co/edit/CEyCzfNu1gWQAe0q8VbP?p=preview

Comment: Sorry , please use this link : http://plnkr.co/edit/9cLRYIaHH4Rl4bO5GAOp?p=preview